# HttpClient SendAsync is not sending cookies

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, .net-core, httpclient

```
var Url = "https://myhost.com/api";
var UrlEncodedContent = GetContent();
var CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using(var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = CookieContainer })
{
    Uri Endpoint = new Uri("https://myhost.com");
    CookieContainer.Add(Endpoint, new Cookie("mycookie", "abc"));

    var Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Url) { Content = UrlEncodedContent };

    var Response = MyHttpClient.SendAsync(Request); 
}
```

The client is not sending the cookies. I have confirmed this by looking at the request in Fiddler.
As far as i can tell this should work correctly.

Comment: Your not using `clientHandler`...

Comment: How are you initializing `MyHttpClient` and where you are setting `clientHandler` to `MyHttpClient`?

Comment: @mxmissile Ah, silly mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to tie the handler to  the client, possibly like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
{
    var Response = client.SendAsync(Request);
}
```